# What does the O notation mean?

Tags: limits, notation

I saw the following notation in a proof that $\lim_{n \to \infty} (\cos{\frac{x}{\sqrt{n}}})^{n}=e^{-x^{2}/2}$ but I don't understand what it means.

$\log{(\cos{\frac{x}{\sqrt{n}}})}=\log{(1-\frac{x^{2}}{2n}}+O(\frac{x^{4}}{n^{2}}))=-\frac{x^{2}}{2n}+O(\frac{x^{4}}{n^2})$

Could someone explain what this means?

Comment: look up "big O notation"

Comment: For example, see [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) on wikipedia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a notation for the remainder term.

For example:

for $x$ ~ $0$ : $e^x = 1 + x + \dfrac{x^2}{2} + O(x^3)$, because the remainder has a growth rate similar to $x^3$ (in this case, the remainder is $\dfrac{x^3}{3!} + \dfrac{x^4}{4!} + ...)$

The formal definition, for two functions $f$ and $g$ about a point $a$, is that:

$f = O(g)$ if $\exists k > 0$ such that, for $x$ in the neighbourhood of $a$, $f(x) \leq k*g(x)$.

*Edit (thanks to mathworker21)* : hence, with $h$ a function, the notation $f = h + O(g)$ means that $f$ equals $h$ plus some remainder term which has a growth rate similar to that of $g$. Hence why it is so often used in Taylor expansions: we often approximate the function up to some term, and need a way to rigorously discard the higher terms.

You'll probably often see the alternative notation $f = o(g)$, which means $f$ is neglictible against $g$ (ie, $g$ grows much faster), which is defined, about a point $a$, as :

$\lim\limits_{x\to a} \dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 0$.

You can then rewrite the Taylor expansion as $e^x = 1 + x + \dfrac{x^2}{2} + o(x^2)$.

Comment: you should say what $f = h+O(g)$ means....

Comment: Good point. Just edited the message, thanks :)

Comment: Thanks. Now I'm just not sure where the log went in the example in the question?

Comment: Well, if $t$ ~ $0$, then you have the Taylor expansion: $log(1+t) = t - t^2 + O(t^4)$. So, in this case, you just have $t = -\dfrac{x^2}{2n}$ :)

Comment: @ArthurLimoge Ah that makes sense now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Given two sequences $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ such that $b_n \geq 0$ for all $n$. We write $$a_n=O(b_n)\;\; (\text{read as $a_n$ is big oh of $b_n$ })$$ if there exists a constant $M>0$ such that $\vert a_n \vert \leq M b_n$

From this definition, $a_n=c_n+ O(b_n)$ means $a_n -c_n= O(b_n)$. That is, there exist $K>0$ such that $\vert a_n-c_n \vert \leq K b_n$

Comment: you should say what $a_n = c_n + O(b_n)$ means.....